# Use new Emojis on older Android devices

Tags: android, emoji

I'm targeting newer Android versions, and make use of their emojis in dialogs.

Older devices, ie Android 5.x don't have certain emojis on-board, thus, when used, they show as a crossed-out box, and they look generally different.

Is there a way to bundle the Android 7.x emojis with the app?

Comment: you can try a library to have specifics emojis : https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: Thanks, but these look ugly as hell. I'm currently checking out https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye-color